# how can I isolate nested brackets?

Tags: regex

Assume I have following sentence :

```
This is a (string) with lots of (brackets) and (to make ((the fun) complete) some are) even nested.
```

What I need is an easy way to isolate all the inner brackets as I need to replace these with curly brackets. So this string becomes as follows

```
This is a (string) with lots of (brackets) and (to make {{the fun} complete} some are) even nested.
```

In theory this means I need a regex that selects on the first round all the left brackets preceded by another left bracket, and all the right brackets followed by another right bracket during a next round. This way I can then use a regex replace to replace the rounded with curly brackets.

But I keep struggling... I tried something like this but it obviously doesn't work, any advice ?

```
(?<=\([^()]*)\(
```

[EDIT]

Well, actually I managed to get it working (using VBA btw) , but probably the purists might not be very impressed, so any advice on improvement is always welcome. I took a 2 step approach, first I replace every left bracket preceded by another left bracket and replace it by a curly one. Then I replace the right bracket preceded by a curly one with a closing curly. And this I loop... Works fine in the end, but of course only if there are no curly ones used already somewhere else

```
Sub testMyFunc()
Call replaceNestedBrackets("This is a (comment in a) string folowed by a (nested and (more (complex)) with (blabla)) comment")
End Sub



Function replaceNestedBrackets(s As String) As String

Dim regEx As New RegExp
regEx.Global = True
Dim colregmatch As MatchCollection
Dim r1, r2 As String
r1 = "{"
r2 = "}"

regEx.Pattern = "(.*\([^)]*)(\()(.*)"

Set colregmatch = regEx.Execute(s)
If colregmatch.Count > 0 Then
    s = colregmatch.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(0) & r1 & colregmatch.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(2)

    regEx.Pattern = "([^{]*{[^\)]*)(\))(.*)"
    Set colregmatch = regEx.Execute(s)
    s = colregmatch.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(0) & r2 & colregmatch.Item(0).SubMatches.Item(2)

    replaceNestedBrackets (s)
End If
replaceNestedBrackets = s

Debug.Print replaceNestedBrackets
End Function
```

Comment: Nesting and balancing are classic problems that "pure" regular expressions aren't suited for, but some regular expression engines have constructs for recursion. What regex engine are you using?

Comment: Why are you restricting yourself to regex? This is easy if you just go through the string a character at a time and track the nesting.

Comment: regex cannot be used to finish bracket matching, typically. regex is the expression to represent regular languages. if you want to know why and what the restriction is, have a search `pumping lemma`. however, perl compatible syntax could do that using recursive regex skill.

Comment: Well, sometimes you have not much choice :-) There might indeed be other and better solutions available but the available tools or possibilities might be limited or resulting in monster code. I prefered regex as it is fairly condensed (in theory). I lack deep knowledge hence I thought it would be feasiblee to match left brackets, preceded by another left bracket before a right bracket appears

Comment: What language? In perl there is a module for that: http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Text-Balanced-2.02/lib/Text/Balanced.pm

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
(\([^()]*)\(([^()]*)\)
```

Replace with `\1{\2}`.
This will replace brackets from the inside out, so you'll have to apply it until it no longer matches.

[See demo.](http://regex101.com/r/hN6lB9/2)

Comment: This will fail for (multiple (sub) (brackets) in the same) outer-bracket set. Seriously, regex simply is not the tool to use here.

Comment: @Dave: Thanks for the hint. I've updated the pattern, there shouldn't be any more problems. Also, I'm pretty sure this task can be solved perfectly reliably with regex - there may be "nicer" solutions, but it's not something that can't be done with regex.

Comment: sort of, it fails on this one for instance : This is a (string) with lots of (brackets) and (to make ((the fun) complete) some are) even nested. Anyway, thanks for the thinking, it helped me constructing what I needed (added in comment above). Might not be the most optimal way but it does the trick

Comment: @Rawing - You could tack on the closing paren (group 3) to complete it. `(\([^()]*)\(([^()]*)\)([^()]*\)) replace $1{$2}$3`. @Workman - the assumption is the paren's _are_ balanced, and the replace_all is in a while() loop, where it starts the search from the BOS every time, until no more replacements are done.

Answer (score 1):

How about a two step replace like the code below. Apologises for my code being in Powershell but its the regexs that is the important bit.

```
$x = "This is a (string) with lots of (brackets) and (to make ((the fun) complete) some are) even nested."
$x = $x -replace '(?<=\([^\)]+)\(', '{'
$x = $x -replace '\)(?=[^\(]+\))', '}'
```

Not fully tested but works for your example.